# javascript date to timestamp problems in firefox and safari ,works in chrome

Tags: javascript

i've got a simple issue which i'm not able to solve .
The code beneath works fine in chrome but gives NaN error in other browsers ...

```
function chkdate()
{

  var todayDate=new Date();
  var date=todayDate.getDate();
  if( date<10)
  {
  date= "0"+date;
   }
  var month=todayDate.getMonth()+1;
 if( month<10)
 {
  month= "0"+month;
  }

 var year=todayDate.getFullYear();

 var hours=todayDate.getHours();
if( hours<10)
{
hours= "0"+hours;
}


 var curdate =  year+"-"+month+"-"+date+"  "+hours+":00:00"  ;

 alert(curdate);
 var curtime= new Date(curdate).getTime();
 alert("current timestamp = "+  curtime) ;      //   <----     **This gives NaN error .**
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you construct the date using one of [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)'s constructors?

```
var curtime = new Date(year, month, date, hours).getTime();
```

This should be cross-browser, as you aren't relying on string parsing to construct the date object.

Answer (score 0):

The format is incorrect when you try to get the cur time

```
var curdate =  year+"-"+month+"-"+date;

 alert(curdate);
 var curtime= new Date(curdate).getTime();
 alert("current timestamp = "+  curtime) ;      //   <----     **This will not give you NaN error .**
```